# Solve for parameters so that a relation is always satisfied

Tags: equation-solving, functions, inequalities

Let's say I have a function parameterized by a number of variables. As a simple example
$$F(x,y) = ax^2 +by^2-cxy+1$$
I want to find some set of values (doesn't really matter what they are) for the parameters so that the relation
$$ F(x,y)>0$$ holds for all points of its domain. So I would want values returned like (1,1,1). I don't need all possible values, just one example where the relation holds.

Is there a function in Mathematica that could do this? The real function I need to operate on is way more complicated and has a few more parameters, but can this be done simply?

I know of `SolveAlways`, but it doesn't like it when I apply relations instead of equalities.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: What do you prefer:`Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, a*x^2 + b*y^2 - c*x*y + 1 > 0], Reals]` or `FindInstance[
 Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, a*x^2 + b*y^2 - c*x*y + 1 > 0], Reals], {a, b,
   c}, Reals, 3]`?

Comment: That second one is perfect! Thank you! Does mathematica have a timeout for such a function? When does it know to stop searching for the parameters, besides a user interrupt, if there are indeed no such parameters that satisfy the relation?

Comment: For example,`Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, a*x^2 + b*y^2 > 0 && a < 0 && b < 0], Reals]` results in `False` and `FindInstance[
 Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, a*x^2 + b*y^2 > 0 && a < 0 && b < 0], 
  Reals], {a, b}, Reals]` produces `{}`.

Comment: @user64494 perhaps you can post as an answer? When a poster is familiar with `SolveAlways` but not `FindInstance` I think that argues that this is not "easily found in documentation". So it would be better to have an answer than to either leave unanswered or closed. PS Also mention `TimeConstrained`.

Comment: PPS I am also guilty of answering questions in comments. Even so...

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Sorry. I was not sure what the OP wanted.

Comment: @user64494 Proposing a possibility in a comment is nothing to apologize for (and I upvoted).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What do you prefer:

```
Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, a*x^2 + b*y^2 - c*x*y + 1 > 0], Reals]
(*(a == 0 && b >= 0 && c == 0) || (a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c == 0) || (a > 0 && 4 a b - c^2 >= 0*)
```

or

```
FindInstance[  Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, a*x^2 + b*y^2 - c*x*y + 1 > 0],Reals],{a, b,c}, Reals,3]
(*{{a->96,b->12,c->0},{a->0,b->275,c->0},{a->0,b->113,c->0}}*)
```

?

Next, `Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, a*x^2 + b*y^2 > 0 && a < 0 && b < 0], Reals]` results in `False` and `FindInstance[ Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, a*x^2 + b*y^2 > 0 && a < 0 && b < 0],    Reals], {a, b}, Reals]` produces `{}`. These outputs say there is no solution.

Answer (score 6):

`SolveAlways[eqns, vars]` according to its documentation is equivalent to `Solve[ ! Eliminate[! eqns, vars]]`.  This can be translated to `Reduce`, which can deal with inequalities:

```
red = Reduce[
  Not@Reduce[Not[a*x^2 + b*y^2 - c*x*y + 1 > 0], {a, b, c}, {x, y}], 
  Reals]
(*
  (c < 0 && b > 0 && a >= c^2/(4 b)) || (c == 0 && b >= 0 && 
     a >= 0) || (c > 0 && b > 0 && a >= c^2/(4 b))
*)
```

This is equivalent to @user64494's result:

```
res = Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, a*x^2 + b*y^2 - c*x*y + 1 > 0], Reals]
Reduce[res \[Implies] red && red \[Implies] res]
(*  True  *)
```