# Optimizing a parameter space search

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, parallelization

This is related to my previous question: [Solve for parameters so that a relation is always satisfied](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235368/solve-for-parameters-so-that-a-relation-is-always-satisfied)

## The Problem

I am searching the parameter space of a large (many terms) function to find where the value of the function is positive semi-definite on its entire domain. Due to physical reasons, the function will always be pretty compact and quickly asymptote to zero, for reasonable choices of the parameters. **All I need is to find 1 set of (non-trivial) values of the parameters so that the function is positive semi-definite everywhere.** For clarity, all variables, functions, and parameters are real.

One function I am using is (in standard form):

```
-(1/2) (1/
     4 o y Coth[n nw] Coth[
      s sw] (-2 n x Sech[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
       2 n x Sech[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2) (-2 s z Sech[
         s (-sw + z^2)]^2 + 2 s z Sech[s (sw + z^2)]^2) + 
    1/4 o x Coth[n nw] Coth[
      s sw] (-2 n y Sech[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
       2 n y Sech[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2) (-2 s z Sech[
         s (-sw + z^2)]^2 + 2 s z Sech[s (sw + z^2)]^2) - (
    2 Coth[2] (-8 x y Sech[2 - x^2 - y^2]^2 Tanh[2 - x^2 - y^2] - 
       8 x y Sech[2 + x^2 + y^2]^2 Tanh[2 + x^2 + y^2]))/(
    4 + z^2))^2 + (-((
    8 z^2 Coth[2] (Tanh[2 - x^2 - y^2] + Tanh[2 + x^2 + y^2]))/(4 + 
      z^2)^3) + (
   2 Coth[2] (Tanh[2 - x^2 - y^2] + Tanh[2 + x^2 + y^2]))/(4 + 
     z^2)^2 - (
   Coth[2] (-2 Sech[2 - x^2 - y^2]^2 + 2 Sech[2 + x^2 + y^2]^2 - 
      8 x^2 Sech[2 - x^2 - y^2]^2 Tanh[2 - x^2 - y^2] - 
      8 x^2 Sech[2 + x^2 + y^2]^2 Tanh[2 + x^2 + y^2]))/(4 + z^2) - (
   Coth[2] (-2 Sech[2 - x^2 - y^2]^2 + 2 Sech[2 + x^2 + y^2]^2 - 
      8 y^2 Sech[2 - x^2 - y^2]^2 Tanh[2 - x^2 - y^2] - 
      8 y^2 Sech[2 + x^2 + y^2]^2 Tanh[2 + x^2 + y^2]))/(
   4 + z^2))^2 - (-(1/4) o x Coth[n nw] Coth[
     s sw] (-2 n x Sech[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
      2 n x Sech[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2) (-2 s z Sech[
        s (-sw + z^2)]^2 + 2 s z Sech[s (sw + z^2)]^2) - 
   1/4 o y Coth[n nw] Coth[
     s sw] (-2 n y Sech[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
      2 n y Sech[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2) (-2 s z Sech[
        s (-sw + z^2)]^2 + 2 s z Sech[s (sw + z^2)]^2) - (
   8 z^2 Coth[2] (Tanh[2 - x^2 - y^2] + Tanh[2 + x^2 + y^2]))/(4 + 
     z^2)^3 + (
   2 Coth[2] (Tanh[2 - x^2 - y^2] + Tanh[2 + x^2 + y^2]))/(4 + 
     z^2)^2 - 
   1/2 o Coth[n nw] Coth[
     s sw] (-2 s z Sech[s (-sw + z^2)]^2 + 
      2 s z Sech[s (sw + z^2)]^2) (-Tanh[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)] + 
      Tanh[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]))^2 - (1/
    4 o x Coth[n nw] Coth[
     s sw] (-2 n x Sech[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
      2 n x Sech[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2) (-2 s z Sech[
        s (-sw + z^2)]^2 + 2 s z Sech[s (sw + z^2)]^2) - (
   Coth[2] (-2 Sech[2 - x^2 - y^2]^2 + 2 Sech[2 + x^2 + y^2]^2 - 
      8 x^2 Sech[2 - x^2 - y^2]^2 Tanh[2 - x^2 - y^2] - 
      8 x^2 Sech[2 + x^2 + y^2]^2 Tanh[2 + x^2 + y^2]))/(4 + z^2) + 
   1/4 o Coth[n nw] Coth[
     s sw] (-2 s z Sech[s (-sw + z^2)]^2 + 
      2 s z Sech[s (sw + z^2)]^2) (-Tanh[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)] + 
      Tanh[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]))^2 - (1/
    4 o y Coth[n nw] Coth[
     s sw] (-2 n y Sech[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
      2 n y Sech[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2) (-2 s z Sech[
        s (-sw + z^2)]^2 + 2 s z Sech[s (sw + z^2)]^2) - (
   Coth[2] (-2 Sech[2 - x^2 - y^2]^2 + 2 Sech[2 + x^2 + y^2]^2 - 
      8 y^2 Sech[2 - x^2 - y^2]^2 Tanh[2 - x^2 - y^2] - 
      8 y^2 Sech[2 + x^2 + y^2]^2 Tanh[2 + x^2 + y^2]))/(4 + z^2) + 
   1/4 o Coth[n nw] Coth[
     s sw] (-2 s z Sech[s (-sw + z^2)]^2 + 
      2 s z Sech[s (sw + z^2)]^2) (-Tanh[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)] + 
      Tanh[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]))^2 - 
 1/2 ((4 z Coth[
      2] (-2 x Sech[2 - x^2 - y^2]^2 + 
       2 x Sech[2 + x^2 + y^2]^2))/(4 + z^2)^2 - 
    3/4 o Coth[n nw] Coth[
      s sw] (-2 n x Sech[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
       2 n x Sech[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2) (-Tanh[s (-sw + z^2)] + 
       Tanh[s (sw + z^2)]) - 
    1/4 o x Coth[n nw] Coth[
      s sw] (-2 n Sech[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
       2 n Sech[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
       8 n^2 x^2 Sech[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 Tanh[
         n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)] - 
       8 n^2 x^2 Sech[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 Tanh[
         n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]) (-Tanh[s (-sw + z^2)] + 
       Tanh[s (sw + z^2)]) - 
    1/4 o y Coth[n nw] Coth[
      s sw] (8 n^2 x y Sech[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 Tanh[
         n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)] - 
       8 n^2 x y Sech[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 Tanh[
         n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]) (-Tanh[s (-sw + z^2)] + 
       Tanh[s (sw + z^2)]) + 
    1/4 o x Coth[n nw] Coth[
      s sw] (-Tanh[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)] + 
       Tanh[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]) (-2 s Sech[s (-sw + z^2)]^2 + 
       2 s Sech[s (sw + z^2)]^2 + 
       8 s^2 z^2 Sech[s (-sw + z^2)]^2 Tanh[s (-sw + z^2)] - 
       8 s^2 z^2 Sech[s (sw + z^2)]^2 Tanh[s (sw + z^2)]))^2 - 
 1/2 ((4 z Coth[
      2] (-2 y Sech[2 - x^2 - y^2]^2 + 
       2 y Sech[2 + x^2 + y^2]^2))/(4 + z^2)^2 - 
    3/4 o Coth[n nw] Coth[
      s sw] (-2 n y Sech[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
       2 n y Sech[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2) (-Tanh[s (-sw + z^2)] + 
       Tanh[s (sw + z^2)]) - 
    1/4 o x Coth[n nw] Coth[
      s sw] (8 n^2 x y Sech[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 Tanh[
         n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)] - 
       8 n^2 x y Sech[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 Tanh[
         n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]) (-Tanh[s (-sw + z^2)] + 
       Tanh[s (sw + z^2)]) - 
    1/4 o y Coth[n nw] Coth[
      s sw] (-2 n Sech[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
       2 n Sech[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
       8 n^2 y^2 Sech[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 Tanh[
         n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)] - 
       8 n^2 y^2 Sech[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]^2 Tanh[
         n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]) (-Tanh[s (-sw + z^2)] + 
       Tanh[s (sw + z^2)]) + 
    1/4 o y Coth[n nw] Coth[
      s sw] (-Tanh[n (-nw + x^2 + y^2)] + 
       Tanh[n (nw + x^2 + y^2)]) (-2 s Sech[s (-sw + z^2)]^2 + 
       2 s Sech[s (sw + z^2)]^2 + 
       8 s^2 z^2 Sech[s (-sw + z^2)]^2 Tanh[s (-sw + z^2)] - 
       8 s^2 z^2 Sech[s (sw + z^2)]^2 Tanh[s (sw + z^2)]))^2
```

In this example, the parameter space is 5 dimensional with parameters $o$, $s$, $sw$, $n$, $nw$. However, I also have cases where it can be up to 10 dimensional, involving functions like `Tanh` and `Exp`. It's worth noting, in the above example function, the only positive definite term is independent of the parameters, so I need to find the parameters that minimize the negative terms so that the positive term dominates everywhere.

## Attempts

Thanks to the insight afforded to me in my previous question, I found the mathematica functions `ForAll`, `resolve`, and `FindInstance` can do the job *for simple functions*. I left the code

```
ForAll[{x,y,z}, Function>=0];
Resolve[%, Reals]
```

running overnight on the above example function and it still didn't have a result in the morning. Perhaps expected since the function is pretty complicated.

I also tried

```
ForAll[{x,y,z}, Function>=0];
FindInstance[%, {s,o,l}, Reals]
```

With similar results. It's actually running as I type this question out and still hasnt returned anything for an hour. I would expect it to be a bit quicker to return atleast *something*, since the function quickly asymptotes to zero, is pretty compact, and whose parameter space is also pretty compact.

I may be interesting to note that that the following code

```
Exists[{x}, x*Exp[-x^2/s] >= 1]
FindInstance[%, s, Reals]
```

fails with error [image] on my version 12.1 even though a simple solution is $s=8$ for example. But this may be worth another post.

## Ideas

It would be great if I can utilize the power of my external GPU to search the parameter space. I was thinking I could partition the parameter space into even chunks and run a findinstance function on each partition on the GPU. However, I dont even know how findinstance works since it seems to be a proprietary algorithm.

Its also worth mentioning that I dont expect the parameters to take on unreasonable values like >1000 or <0.0000001. Perhaps I could cut out a (sufficiently large) region of the parameter space, partition it, and search the partitions using a parallelized version of `FindInstance`?

Since this problem is largely numerical, it should be possible to parallelize it and run it on a GPU. Thats my thoughts anyways.

I guess you could classify this problem as an optimization problem, since were basically trying to maximize the area under the curve.

I appreciate any insight you can give!

Comment: Could you include the MATHEMATICA formula instead of Latex?

Comment: yes, of course. I suppose that would make more sense!

Comment: This is likely to be very hard by brute force: the parameter space is too large. Do you have intuition / physical reasons to suggest or limit the values of the parameters?

Comment: Luckily, yes. I have another function that is worked into this one whose parameters arent constrained at all (I set them myself). So I expect the parameters used in the example function above are of the same order as the ones I set myself. I dont expect the parameters to be any larger than 10 or smaller than 0.00001 for example. How would I scan over a continuous range of real numbers like that?